# Vertical image larger than parent div

Tags: html, css, image, size

so I checked other posts, but no answers helped me. So I have an image inside a div. I put a specific height/width size of the div to show the ratio of the div, and the image inside is higher, so it always goes outside of the div.

I want to make the image smaller so that it is vertically as high as the div, and the width would adjust accordingly. Can anyone help??

```html
<div class="intro-pic" style="height: 343px; ; width: 614px; overflow: hidden
;">
  <div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IMDdLW9.png" title="user engagement" style="width: 100%;" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: max-height: 343px;
max-width: 614px; for the img

Comment: the div is responsive, I just did not know how to set a ratio size for the div. The size in the jsfiddle is an example size. I need the image to be responsive to the div size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<div class="intro-pic" style="height: 343px; ; width: 614px; overflow: hidden
;">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IMDdLW9.png" title="user engagement" style="height: 100%;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the extra div is also preventing the img to use its parent's css properties. It is unnecessary.
http://jsfiddle.net/2q94nfq6/1/

```
<div class="intro-pic" style="height: 343px; ; width: 614px; overflow: hidden
;">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IMDdLW9.png" title="user engagement" style="height: 100%;width: 100%;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining your div in pixels then you should use **max-width property of css** under style. The max-width property is used to set the maximum width of a given element.